# How to overcome Row size too large (> 8126) error on Google-Cloud MySQL5.7 Second Generation

Tags: innodb, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

Google Cloud MySQL Engine supports the InnoDB storage engine only.

I am getting the following error when creating a table with 300 columns.

> [Err] 1118 - Row size too large (> 8126).

Changing some columns to `TEXT` or `BLOB` may help. In the current row format, the `BLOB` prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.

I tried creating a table with the combination of some columns as text types and some others as blob types as well but it did not work.
Even modifying `innodb_log_file_size` is not possible, as it is not allowed on the Google Cloud-SQL Platform.

Comment: You haven't shared the table definition or any information about what the table is for. Lacking any specific information, I would assume that your table with 300 columns is not normalized properly. Follow principles of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and do not make a table with 300 columns.

Comment: @BillKarwin
Thank you for quick answer. But here it is requirement to keep data in non normalized form and create tables based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Vertical Partitioning"

A table with lots of columns is pushing several limits; you hit one of them.  There are several reasonable workarounds, Vertical Partitioning may be the best, especially if many are `TEXT`/`BLOB`.

Instead of a single table, have multiple tables with the same `PRIMARY KEY`, except that one *may* be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  `JOIN` them together as needed to collect the columns.  You could even have `VIEWs` to hide the fact that you split up the table.  I recommend grouping the columns by some logical grouping based on the application and which  columns are needed 'together'.

Do *not* splay an array of things across columns; instead, have another table with multiple rows to handle the repetition.  Example:  address1, state1, country1, address2, state2, country2.

Do not use `CHAR` or `BINARY` except for truly fixed-length columns.  Most of such are very short.  Also, most `CHAR` columns should be `CHARACTER SET ascii`, not utf8.  (Think, `country_code`, zipcode`, md5`.)

`innodb_log_file_size` is only indirectly related to your Question.  What is it's value?

Directly related is `innodb_page_size`, which defaults to `16K`, and virtually no one ever changes.  I would expect Cloud Engines to prohibit changing it.

(I'm with Bill on desiring more info about your schema -- so we can be more specific about how to help you.)

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestion.
I followed this , It worked for me. 
I have created two tables and defined primary key in each table by creating HASH of all columns values of source locations first and use that HashString in both tables to match rows from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much option here. InnoDB default page size is 16KB, and you must design your tables so at least two rows fit in a page. That's where the limit of 8126 bytes per row comes from.

Variable-length columns like VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB, and TEXT can be longer, because data exceeding the row size limit can be stored on extra pages. To take advantage of this, you must enable the Barracuda table format, and choose ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC.

In config:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_default_row_format = DYNAMIC;
```

I don't know if these settings are already enabled in Google Cloud SQL, or if they allow you to change these settings.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format.html for more information

Again, the advantage of DYNAMIC row format only applies to variable-length data types. If you have 300 columns that are fixed-length, like CHAR, then it doesn't help.

By the way, innodb_log_file_size has nothing to do with this error about row size.

Comment: innodb_file_format & innodb_default_row_format options are not available on GCP

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want to do on a Cloud SQL instance, first off run this to set the `innodb_strict_mode` variable:

```
SET innodb_strict_mode = 0 ;
```

After that you should be able to create your table.